# Generating fuction of the Bessel Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, generating-functions, bessel-functions

Consider the Bessel DEQ:  $$x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-\alpha^2)y=0$$

Find a function $F$ such that $$F(x,t)=\sum_{\alpha=-\infty}^\infty J_{\alpha}(x)t^{\alpha}$$

I received a few instructions:

a) first compute $\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}F(x,t)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(x,t))$

b) Then exploiting the results of the first hint, write down the PDE that $F(x,t)$ has to satisfy.

c) Then given the ansatz $F(x,t)=\exp(xT(t))$ find the two ODEs that $T(t)$ has to satisfy ($T(t)=t^r$)

d) Last, show that $T(t)=-T(1/t)$ which will fix all constants in the generating function which gives the generating function of the Bessel functions.

I'm already running into problems with the first hint, I'm not sure how to take the $n$th derivative of the $F(x,t)$ function and I would really appreciate some assistance!

***EDITs: Calculated the partial derivatives according to the helpful comments, but now stuck on the second part!***

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}J_{\alpha}(x)=\frac{1}{2}(J_{\alpha-1}(x)-J_{\alpha+1}(x))$$

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}J_{\alpha}(x)=\frac{1}{4}(J_{\alpha-2}(x)-2J_{\alpha}(x)+J_{\alpha+2}(x))$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}F(x,t)=\Sigma_{-\infty}^{\infty}J_{\alpha}(x)\alpha^2t^{\alpha-1}$$

Now for the second part, as @Gary mentioned in the comments I need to have $\sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {(x^2 J''_n (x) + xJ'_n (x) + (x^2  - n^2 )J_n (x))t^n } \;\; (=0)$. But as the second hint suggests, i need to have a PDE but not sure where the time partial dertivative should be...Thanks

***2nd Edit***

With the help of Gary i have :$$x^2\Sigma_{\alpha=-\infty}^{\infty}J_{\alpha}^2(x)t^{\alpha}+x\Sigma_{\alpha=-\infty}^{\infty}J_{\alpha}(x)t^{\alpha}+x^2\Sigma_{\alpha=-\infty}^{\infty}J_{\alpha}(x)t^{\alpha}-t^2\Sigma_{\alpha=-\infty}^{\infty}J_{\alpha}(x)t^{\alpha}$$

and the PDE follows:

$$x^2F_{xx}+xF_x+x^2F-tF_t-t^2F_{tt}=0$$

Can someone give me a hint on how to find the two ordinary differential equations asked in c)?

Comment: You need to consider only $n=1$ and $n=2$.

Comment: @Gary Can you elaborate on why that is? And in that case can i simply use the properties of the Bessel function (i remember there are a few that relate to the first and the second derivatives

Comment: It is always good to know the objective of a computation when it is possible to get it. Here you have to show that the so-called "**generating function**" (remind this name) of the Bessel functions with **integral index** is $\sum_n J_n(x)t^n=\exp(x \frac{t-t^{-1}}{2})$

Comment: @jeanmarie I actually know that one:) i went through first 10 pages of google search of generating functions for Bessel fucntion, and unfortunately here i have to follow the hints:)

Comment: @JerryCohen Your aim is to express $$
\sum\limits_{n =  - \infty }^\infty  {(x^2 J''_n (x) + xJ'_n (x) + (x^2  - n^2 )J_n (x))t^n } \;\; (=0)
$$ in terms of the various derivatives of $F(x,t)$.

Comment: Got some progress, not sure how the PDE should look like, i would simply plug in the partial derivatives of the generating function like @Gary 's comment but wondering where the time partial derivative should go or whether its relavent at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exercise asked you to compute $\frac{{\partial ^n F(x,t)}}{{\partial x^n }}$ and not $\frac{{\partial ^n J_\alpha  (x)}}{{\partial x^n }}$. Likewise, it was suggested to compute $\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {t\frac{{\partial F(x,t)}}{{\partial t}}} \right)$ and not just ${\frac{{\partial F(x,t)}}{{\partial t}}}$ (which is probably just a typo). We have
$$
\frac{{\partial ^n F(x,t)}}{{\partial x^n }} = \sum\limits_{\alpha  =  - \infty }^\infty  {J_\alpha ^{(n)} (x)t^\alpha  } 
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {t\frac{{\partial F(x,t)}}{{\partial t}}} \right) = \sum\limits_{\alpha  =  - \infty }^\infty  {\alpha ^2 J_\alpha  (x)t^{\alpha-1}  } ,
$$
respectively. Now what is the series form of
$$
x^2 \frac{{\partial ^2 F(x,t)}}{{\partial x^2 }} + x\frac{{\partial F(x,t)}}{{\partial x}} + x^2 F(x,t) - t\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {t\frac{{\partial F(x,t)}}{{\partial t}}} \right)\,?
$$

Comment: Ah thannk you!!! I wasnt sure. where $ t\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {t\frac{{\partial F(x,t)}}{{\partial t}}} \right)\,$
 should be... Thou is there a reason you have $ t\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {t\frac{{\partial F(x,t)}}{{\partial t}}} \right)\,$ instead of $ \frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {t\frac{{\partial F(x,t)}}{{\partial t}}} \right)\,$...i.e. the one more $t$?

Comment: Because the power series should run in $t^\alpha$ and not $t^{\alpha-1}$.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask so many questions...but why would I need the series form ? Indicia equation ?

Comment: Write down the series expansion in powers of $t$ for that big expression I gave you at the end. Can you see that each coefficient is $0$? Hence that big expression equals $0$. Bumm! You have a partial differential equation for $F$.

Comment: I feel really stupid now..im sorry, crying a bit typing this follow up question. When you say power series, i thought the power series of the function $F(x,t)=\Sigma a_nb_nx^nt^n$ but what do you mean by series expansion in powers of $t$-.-.

Comment: Or just multiply it out? $t\frac{\partial }{{\partial t}}\left( {t\frac{{\partial F(x,t)}}{{\partial t}}} \right)\,=\Sigma \alpha^2J{\alpha}(x)t^{\alpha}?
$

Comment: Yes, powers in $t$ only. The coefficient of $t^\alpha$ will be exactly the Bessel equation with $J_\alpha(x)$ in place of $y(x) $.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused...but i wrote the series form $\Sigma a_nb_nn(n-1)x^nt^n+ \Sigma a_nb_nnx^nt^n+\Sigma a_nb_nx^{n+2}t^n-\alpha^2J_{\alpha}(x)t^{\alpha}$ set $n=\alpha$ which does look like the Bessel equation

Comment: I don't know what you are doing. Based on my answer, it should be a simple and straightforward task. Sorry I don't know how to give you more help.

Comment: I don't you why differentiation with respect to x appears for you. I showed you what the derivatives of F look like with respect to x. Keep it in that form, with derivatives of the J Bessel in the sum, like I wrote. You overcomplicate a simple task.

Comment: Yeah sorry....Let me try again like you said $$\Sigma_{\alpha=-\infty}^{\infty}J_{\alpha}^2(x)t^{\alpha}+\Sigma_{\alpha=-\infty}^{\infty}J_{\alpha}(x)t^{\alpha}+x^2\Sigma_{\alpha=-\infty}^{\infty}J_{\alpha}(x)t^{\alpha}-\Sigma_{\alpha=-\infty}^{\infty}J_{\alpha}(x)t^{\alpha}$$

Comment: Couldnt edit the last line, there is an $\alpha^2$ in the last term and $x^2$ and $x$ in the first and second. ok im really sorry...

Comment: Now write it as a single sum by collecting the coefficients of $t^\alpha$.

Comment: That 'd be 
$$t^{\alpha}\{\Sigma_{\alpha = - \infty}^{\infty}\{(x^2J_{\alpha}^2(x))+(xJ_{\alpha}(x))+(x^2J_{\alpha}(x))-(\alpha^2J_{\alpha}(x))\}\}$$

Comment: You should have derivatives and not second and first power in the first two terms. By $(n)$ I meant $n$th derivative. You cannot factor out $t^\alpha$ since the sum is over $\alpha$. It seems that you have some fundamental gaps in your understanding of some basic concepts in analysis. You should gain a solid understanding before working on problems like this one.